# Ayuda con tabla dinamica

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html5, ajax

Estoy con un inconveniente de manejo de tablas.
Necesito mostrar datos de dos tablas, que ya tengo almacenadas en la base de datos, la primera es servicios, muestra los servicios existentes y al hacer click sobre uno de estos servicios necesito que me muestre otra tabla de materiales que se requieran para realizar este servicio, la verdad no se como hacerlo, soy nuevo en programacion web, se que esto se puede hacer con ajax, pero no se como, si alguien me puede dar un ejemplo, creo que podria solucionar mi drama.

Algo similar a esto es lo que quiero conseguir:

Aqui esta seleccionado "Pared de 0,15"
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui esta Seleccionado "Piso de Ceramica" [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que podés hacer es, dado que es una consulta dinámica por fila, asignar un valor en un campo `data` al `<tr/>` que vas a seleccionar. De esa forma, cuando hagás la consulta `$.ajax()` podrás mandar el valor que querés filtrar.

Algo así:

```js
// Esta variable simula la respuesta de la llamada AJAX
const valoresAjax = {
  // Respuesta de la consulta enviando el parámetro codigo = 1
  "codigo1": [
    {
      "codigo": 5,
      "material": "Ladrillo común",
      "cantidad": "95 un",
      "precioUnitario": "574",
      "precio": "37.282"
    },
    {
      "codigo": 8,
      "material": "Cemento Portland",
      "cantidad": "11.8 kg",
      "precioUnitario": "960",
      "precio": "5.510"
    },
    {
      "codigo": 22,
      "material": "Cal Hidratada",
      "cantidad": "5.53 kg",
      "precioUnitario": "1.125",
      "precio": "6.221"
    },
    {
      "codigo": 3,
      "material": "Arena Lavada",
      "cantidad": "0.05 m3",
      "precioUnitario": "52.786",
      "precio": "2.639"
    },
  ],
  // Respuesta de la consulta enviando el parámetro codigo = 5
  "codigo5": [
    {
      "codigo": 5,
      "material": "Cerámica Esmaltada",
      "cantidad": "10",
      "precioUnitario": "30.000",
      "precio": "300.000"
    },
    {
      "codigo": 8,
      "material": "Agramassa",
      "cantidad": "50 kg",
      "precioUnitario": "32.000",
      "precio": "1.600.000"
    },
    {
      "codigo": 22,
      "material": "Pastina Klaukol",
      "cantidad": "12 kg",
      "precioUnitario": "10.000",
      "precio": "120.000"
    }
  ]
}
// Código HTML de tabla de detalle para creación dinámica
const tablaDetalleHTML = '<h3>Material por Cada Servicio</h3><table><thead><tr><th>Código</th><th>Material</th><th>Cantidad</th><th>Precio Unitario</th><th>Precio</th></tr></thead><tbody></tbody></table>';

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.tablaPrincipal').on('click', 'tr', function(){
    // Obtener el valor del campo data-id de la fila
    // que recibe el evento click
    let paramId = $(this).data('id');
    
    // Este bloque representa la llamada AJAX
    /*$.ajax(
      url: url,
      data: {codigo: paramId},
      success: function(response){
      
        // Esta asignación está aquí como explicación de la asignación
        // de la variable response.
        let valoresAjax = {};
        valoresAjax[paramId] = response*/
        
        // Esta línea no es necesaria en la aplicación real
        // ya que valoresAjax[paramId] representa el response AJAX
        let response = valoresAjax[paramId];
        
        // Insertar el bloque HTML de tablaDetalle en el div.tablaDetalle
        $('.tablaDetalle').html($(tablaDetalleHTML));
        
        // La función map sirve para iterar los elementos de un arreglo
        response.map(f => {
          $('<tr><td>' + f.codigo + '</td><td>' + f.material + '</td><td>' + f.codigo + '</td><td>' + f.codigo + '</td><td>' + f.codigo + '</td></tr>').appendTo('.tablaDetalle tbody');
        });
      /*}
    )
    */
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background: #BFE5D0;
}

.tablaDetalle table {
  background: #C2E9F0;
}

table tr {
  border: solid 1px #74827B;
}

.tablaPrincipal tbody tr {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tablaPrincipal tbody tr:hover {
  background: #7CAE92;
}

table td, table th {
  padding: 5px;
  border-right: solid 1px #A8B5DB;
}

table td:last-child, table th:last-child {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Servicios</h3>
<table class="tablaPrincipal">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Código</th>
      <th>Servicio</th>
      <th>Dimensión</th>
      <th>Precio</th>
      <th>Eliminar</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-id="codigo1">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Pared de 0,15m</td>
      <td>25 m2</td>
      <td>14</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-id="codigo5">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Piso de Cerámica</td>
      <td>10 m2</td>
      <td>25</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div class="tablaDetalle">
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario Niche, fue genial. Saludos!!

Answer (score 1):

Muy buenas Diego Arce

Hay un codigo que yo utilizo, que se refiere al completo, con lo que tu buscas.

> Igual esto te ayuda https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Puedes utilizarlo usando PHP, AJAX y JAVASCRIPT a la vez

Comment: Gracias Ruben, lo probaré

Answer (score -1):

No se si mi respuesta sea muy burda y poco optima, pero con lo poco que sé, creo que puedes  agregar un `<a href="#"></a>` en las consultas, donde en el # pones un modal, para cunado de click en el modal salga la tabla que necesites, bueno, al menos así es como creo que podrías hacer por que la verdad no se mucho de AJAX o JAVASCRIPT.